# Avoid duplicated entries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can't avoid duplicated records in this query:

```
select 
    u.employeeid [id_empleado], a.LOGDATETIME [checada], ASSETID [dispositivo]
from 
    [dbo].[AccessLog] a
inner join 
    [dbo].[BiometricDevice] b on (b.ID = a.MORPHOACCESSID)
inner join 
    [dbo].[User_] u on (a.userid = u.id)
order by 
    id_empleado, checada asc
```

Output example:

```
id_empleado checada dispositivo
14907   2016-08-22 13:25:40.000 02
14907   2016-08-22 23:32:10.000 01
14907   2016-08-23 12:08:03.000 01
14907   2016-08-23 22:51:39.000 02
14907   2016-08-24 12:29:07.000 01
14907   2016-08-26 23:24:55.000 01
14907   2016-08-30 00:29:08.000 01
16034   2016-10-05 12:51:51.000 GERENCIA
16034   2016-10-06 04:03:56.000 GERENCIA
16034   2016-10-08 11:37:29.000 GERENCIA
16034   2016-10-09 10:52:51.000 GERENCIA
16034   2016-10-10 00:51:16.000 GERENCIA
16034   2016-10-10 11:19:42.000 GERENCIA
```

What I need:

```
id_empleado checada dispositivo
14907   2016-08-22 13:25:40.000 02
16034   2016-10-10 11:19:42.000 GERENCIA
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what `checada` and `dispositivo` should be selected in the output.  Please clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear, I don't  want to have duplicated "id_empleado", so I need only one "id_empleado"

Comment: you can simply use DISTINCT to avoid duplicates from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. It selects the first `checada` and `dispositivo` associated with a given `id_empleado`.

```
select [id_empleado], [checada], [dispositivo]
from (
    select u.employeeid [id_empleado],a.LOGDATETIME [checada], ASSETID [dispositivo],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.employeeid ORDER BY a.LOGDATETIME) as seq
    from [dbo].[AccessLog] a
    inner join [dbo].[BiometricDevice] b on (b.ID = a.MORPHOACCESSID)
    inner join [dbo].[User_] u on (a.userid = u.id)) as a
where seq = 1
order by id_empleado, checada asc
```

Output:

```
id_empleado checada                 dispositivo
----------- ----------------------- ------------------------------
14907       2016-08-22 13:25:40.000 02
16034       2016-10-05 12:51:51.000 GERENCIA
```

---

**Reference:** MSDN [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: In some cases repits information:
31724 2016-08-22 11:15:26.000 06
31734 2016-08-22 09:51:28.000 06

Comment: These are two different `id_empleado` (31724 and 31734).  What output do you expect in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select t.* 
from 
    (select 
         u.employeeid, a.logdatetime, assetid,
         row_number() over (partition by u.employeeid order by u.employeeid) as r   
     from 
         [dbo].[AccessLog] a  
     inner join 
         [dbo].[BiometricDevice] b on (b.ID = a.MORPHOACCESSID)   
     inner join 
         [dbo].[User_] u on (a.userid = u.id)   
) t  
where r = 1
```

Comment: I get this error:
Msg 10753, Level 15, State 3, Line 15
The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use **GROUP BY** or **ROW_NUMBER()** as mentioned in the above posts

```
select 
    u.employeeid [id_empleado], MAX(a.LOGDATETIME) [checada], MAX(ASSETID) [dispositivo]
from 
    [dbo].[AccessLog] a
inner join 
    [dbo].[BiometricDevice] b on (b.ID = a.MORPHOACCESSID)
inner join 
    [dbo].[User_] u on (a.userid = u.id)
GROUP BY u.employeeid
order by 
    id_empleado, checada asc
```

Comment: @jviramontes Please mark it as answer if its working.